# How can I use a namespace in a Rake task dependency?

Tags: ruby, namespaces, rake

When defining rake tasks, it is possible to use namespaces, like this:

```
namespace :demolition do
  task :fire_bazooka do
    puts "kaboom!"
  end
end
```

This could be called like `rake demolition:fire_bazooka`.

It is also possible to specify prerequisites for a task, like this:

```
# Single prerequisite
task :fire_bazooka => :load_bazooka do ....

# Multiple prerequisites
task :fire_bazooka => [:safety_check, :load_bazooka]
```

But **how can I use a namespaced task as a prerequisite?** This, obviously, does not work:

```
task :photograph_destruction => :demolition:fire_bazooka
```

Comment: oh you get a +1 from me because the examples are practically identical to my use case :)

Comment: @conny - can I come work where you work? :D

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You already found the solution (name as a string).

You may extend this answer. There is no need to define namespaces and tasks with symbols. You can use Strings.

Doing this, you have the advantage of same type for definition and usage of task names.

Your example looks like this:

```
namespace 'demolition' do
  task 'fire_bazooka' do
    puts "kaboom!"
  end
end

task 'photograph_destruction' => "demolition:fire_bazooka" do
  puts "snapping pics! yay!"
end
```

Answer (score 12):

### Figured it out

You just have to give the name as a string, like this:

```
task :photograph_destruction => "demolition:fire_bazooka" do
  puts "snapping pics! yay!"
end
```

#### Update

As @mikeycgto and @mipadi pointed out, a quoted symbol (note the leading `:`) will also work:

```
task :photograph_destruction => :'demolition:fire_bazooka' do
  puts "snapping pics! yay!"
end
```

Comment: This might also work and it's still a symbol: `:'demolition:fire_bazooka'`

Comment: You can also use single quotes in a symbol, like so: `:'demolition:fire_bazooka'`.

Comment: You can also convert a string to a symbol with `'demolition:firebazooka'.to_sym` -- This isn't necessarily much better than the preceding comments but it does help convey the idea of what's going on..